# PDB or ePUB format ebook reader for iPhone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, epub, pdb-palm

I would like to ask you guys if there is any example source code available for Ebook reader for iPhone that loads any of these format files (PDB or ePUB).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is one good example for this.....
https://github.com/st3fan/iphone-bookreader